# some tex files use a % before footnote?

Tags: comments, latexdiff

I simply can't understand the difference: in some of my tex files I see something like this:

```
some text with a footnote\footnote{some footnote}
```

while in other files i see:

```
some text with a footnote%
\footnote{some footnote%
}
```

Whils this seems to make absolutely no difference to output, it does mess things up for `latexdiff` when trying to compare two files. Can anyone explain why one is preferred over the other and a good way to reconcile things like this so it wouldn't show up as a difference in `latexdiff`. Also, what's the best way to get rid of the `%`, regex replace? (PS: I know that `%` is simply a comment and presumably does nothing when placed at the end of the line)

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: thanks for the ref: can you mention why someone might want to do this in my context? it seems unnecessary..

Comment: It might be a way to separate document elements so it's clearly visible that there's a footnote. In order to do this, which may also allow them to use code-folding (editor dependent), they place it on a line of its own but would then require the use of `%` to avoid spurious spaces in the output.

Comment: makes sense, thank you. any thoughts on how to make latexdiff ignore things like this without doing a regex replace on the doc?

Comment: No; I don't use `latexdiff` unfortunately.

Comment: understood - thanks for the help, hopefully somebody else sees this with some additional thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use perl in a terminal to delete `%` followed by a newline. Like this:

```
cat LaTeXfil1.tex | perl -p -i -e 's/%\n//g;'
```

So instead of

```
latexdiff LaTeXfil1.tex LaTeXfil2.tex
```

you should be able to use latexdiff like this:

```
latexdiff <(cat LaTeXfil1.tex | perl -p -i -e 's/%\n//g;') LaTeXfil2.tex
```

I can not test it, as I do not know exactly what latexdiff does or what output is expected.

Comment: yeh that's what i essentially ended up doing but in emacs

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: latexdiff will not work from a pipe as it needs to read input files twice. So the command as written will not work (but the idea is clear and easily implementable with a temporary file)

Comment: @frederik have you tried it? I am not using a pipe, but a process substitution. I do not know enough about process substitution to tell if it will work or not but I found this "Process substitution uses /dev/fd/<n> files to send the results of the process(es) within parentheses to another process." which suggests that it already uses a temp file, that can be read twice.

Comment: I should have set input redirection instead of pipe. As latexdiff does not read from stdin, I expected it to fail. But actually I stand corrected, it does indeed work, so it's not input redirection in spite of the < sign. Learned something new about bash today. Thank you for pointing this out